# Preventing mouse from leaving Node?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a VBox that enters an edit mode if the user chooses to. How can I prevent the mouse from the leaving that VBox and clicking on other things?

Alternatively, how do I BLOCK OUT the rest of the application and make sure they aren't clickable? (Making them a lighter tint would show this too. Like how Adobe Illustrator enters a shape's edit mode).

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate `Pane` to your layout and set its visibility to false and its style to something like `-fx-background-color: #00000077`. Add your `VBox` on top of that `Pane` (but not as a child of the `Pane`). Your layout should be something like this:

```
layout
   -> controls
   -> pane
   -> vbox
```

Where `layout` is your main layout node, `controls` is your node containing most of your interface, `pane` is the dimming `Pane`, and `vbox` is the `VBox` you want to be emphasized. The children should be added in that order.

Whenever a node in `vbox` has focus, show `pane` (and hide it when focus is lost or your accept the user's input). `pane`, when visible, will prevent the user from interacting with other parts of your interface, specifically any node within `layout` (except `vbox`).